# Restricting on-the-fly editing of grub2 menuentries

Tags: grub2, menu, editing

Is there a way to disable the `e' to edit commands before booting` option in the GRUB2 menu?

I want all menuentries to be available to all users (so password restricting them is not an option) but restrict the ability of users to change said menuentries.

Is that possible?

Comment: AFAIK, password restriction only disables editing but not the visibility of menuentries (to do this there is a `lock` feature).

Comment: Well I added this at the end of ***/etc/grub.d/40_custom***:

    set superuser=admin
    password_pbkdf2  admin <Very_long_hash>

After running `update-grub` and rebooted I was prompted for password unconditionally.

Comment: So where can I find documentation for this `lock` feature? I looked both in the official manual and the Ubuntu specific but it does not mention any lock option.

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: Nope. I gave-up.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 18.04 it started to work after I added

```
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=y
```

to /etc/default/grub. So essentially the steps are:

Generate password with:

```
grub-mkpasswd-pbkdf2
```

Copy the following lines to the end of /etc/grub.d/40_custom and replace the password with the password from the output above. This will password protect grub completely:

```
set superusers="grubadm"
password_pbkdf2 grubadm grub.pbkdf2.sha512.10000.D23193A0BE80A8D94606716D2DBE18C1AC77563FD87B7DA41824467E9393EBFFAF8B909DFAD83293325016EF6DA112EBAC819B3196F2D9F764F56E037E4EB86A.78AAD14971909106B4BE80AB6BF704804E67D5486966D9A85289E5449F08BD54E55B83B28CF0A4F2B4D486F2136439B7786135B8D59C611BF9DE2CDE965DB791
```

Allow selection of boot entries for different kernel versions. edit `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` and

1. Insert `--unrestricted` after `${CLASS}` in the line `echo "menuentry '$(title "$os" [...]` in function linux_entry in `/etc/grub.d/10_linux`, e.g.

   ```
   echo "menuentry '$(echo "$title" | grub_quote)' ${CLASS} --unrestricted \$menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-$version-$type-$boot_device_id' {" | sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/"
   ```
2. Insert  `--unrestricted` after `${CLASS}` in the line ´echo "menuentry '$(echo "$os" [...]`in function linux_entry in`/etc/grub.d/10_linux`, e.g.

   ```
   echo "menuentry '$(echo "$os" | grub_quote)' ${CLASS} --unrestricted \$menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-$boot_device_id' {" | sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/"
   ```

Add the following line to /etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=y
```

Rebuild grub conf file by executing

```
update-grub
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [wiki:](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Passwords)

> If any form of GRUB 2 password protection is enabled, the superuser's name and password are required to gain access to the GRUB 2 command line and menu-editing modes.

This appears to mean that you need to allow unpriviledged users to boot:

> The GRUB 2 menu can contain protected and unprotected items. The format for protecting a menu item consists of adding the user access information to the menuentry title line.
>
> The presence of --unrestricted disables password protection.

Comment: But if you have the `--unrestricted` flag on a menu entry then everybody can edit that menuentry. What I need is to have all menuentries available to all but restrict users from changing menuentries or going to the grub2 command line

I remember this was working on grub legacy but apparently is no longer supported on grub2.  From the grub2 article on Ubuntu help:
"There are currently no options to prevent the command-line usage of Grub. Doing so would restrict boot-loading to just the menu options and that is not considered wise"

Comment: I believe the opinion is that restricting the grub is easy to circumvent anyway, all you have to do is hide the grub.cfg. Have you tried having a guest password, who can only boot stuff?

Comment: OK imagine a kiosk. No CD or USB is accessible externally and the bios is locked. You want to prevent script kiddies from messing with grub and breaking your system. Also legit users have no way to know the password. What bothers me is that exactly this scenario was working under the previous grub version.

Comment: I think you can harden against someone hiding grub.cfg using [grub-mkstandalone](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/grub-mkstandalone.1.html)